# Как склонять мужскую фамилию Макарь?

Tags: склонение-фамилий

Мужская фамилия Макарь...склоняться будет МакарЕм, не МакарЁм?

Answer (score 1):

Это как желает обладатель фамилии. По умолчанию: если МакАрь – то МакарЁм, если МАкарь – то МАкарем.